# Java is not working in my PC

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer

I had installed Java in my PC and it was working perfectly. Suddenly something went wrong and now I m not able to open swing applications and its showing the error 'Java not found'. But I can run the Eclipse IDE which also needed Java to run. So I decide to reinstall the Java, but when I tried to uninstall the Java it shows the Error 1723 - There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. So I have installed a new JDK in another location and set the PATH. Still I am not able to run the Swing application.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: This swing application, as you put it... how are you running it?  From the CLI?  Is it an executable jar?  Or did someone package it as an .exe?

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for SuperUser? You could look into the Java path variables.

Comment: The exe is a wrapper around the jar file or is a wrapper on a bat file? Meaning was it created using something like jsmooth? or was it created using bat to exe converter? If it was a bat file initially, then may be the location of java on the bat file was hard coded to the wrong path? If it was a wrapper on a jar file, then maybe the jar file did not have the correct manifest in it.

Comment: the application was created using Jsmooth. So I guess it may not be the issue with the Java installation rite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running your swing application? 
If it's from the command line like `java mySwingApp` and you're getting `java not found` then your `PATH` isn't set properly. Make sure that the java/bin directory is on your PATH not just the top level directory. You can test your PATH by just typing `java` in a console window - it should print the java help page.

If you're not running from a terminal like above, then you may need to set a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which points to your java installation folder. Here's a tutorial on setting `JAVA_HOME` 
[Setting JAVA_HOME](http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html)

Hope this helps,

Will

Answer (score 1):

This is close to jakob's answer, about trying to get your Java install setup correctly again, just with a little more detail.

I had a similar problem on my Windows 7 box where I was trying to uninstall Java and do a clean install of a newer version.  Something got messed up and I would get the 1723 error message during the uninstall and attempted reinstall.  Here's information about how I was able to fix the problem, and maybe this will help you:

Look at the log files for the uninstall/reinstall.  On Windows 7 they can be found at `c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\`

The `java_install.log`didn't show any extra information, but I had several `MSI#####` log files that contained error messages about the failed uninstall.  The message was: `Error 1723.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action UninstallJRE, entry: MSIUninstallJRE, library: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\regutils.dll`

There was indeed no `regutils.dll` file, and not even the `bin`directory was there. So I copied over a `regutils.dll` file from another computer, ran the uninstaller, and it worked.  Then the new clean install of Java also worked.

So take a look at your logfiles and hopefully that will give you more detailed information about the 1723 error.

Answer (score 0):

This usally happens when you delete Java files manually.
If you try to uninstall Java and it fails, it generates a log file.
Should be in C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp
Almost at the end the missing file(s) can be found.
Try to copy that file(s) from a working installation to your computer.
Then you should be able to uninstall your Java and install a new version.

Comment: How can I find the missing files in the Temp folder.